# How to remove a Form.Element.Observer

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm using Prototype 1.6.
I create a new Form.Element.Observer, but is there a way to then remove it/stop it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work :

```
var obs = new Form.Element.Observer(element, frequency, callback);
obs.stop();
```

Comment: Yep, but there is one on PeriodicalExecuter : 
Form.Element.Observer inherits Abstract.TimedObserver which inherits PeriodicalExecuter ;)

Comment: You're right, because I was looking at 1.5.2
1.6.1 inheirits it from PeriodicalExecuter properly.